# Hodge Decompositions and Gamma Factors of Hasse--Weil L-Functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, l-functions

Let $X$ be a projective variety over a number field $K$. If $\mathfrak{p}\unlhd\mathcal{O}_K$ is a prime ideal we can regard the Euler factor of its $m$th Hasse-Weil $L$-Function at $\mathfrak{p}$ as the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius at $\mathfrak{p}$ acting on the $\mathfrak{p}$-inertia invariants of its $m$th l-adic etale cohomology group, where $l$ is different from the residual characteristic at $\mathfrak{p}$. For example, when $m=1$ and $X=E$ is an elliptic curve we recover the more concrete definition in terms of Galois action on the $l$-adic Tate module.

I'm afraid to say that my question is a little vague. I understand that the Archimdean Euler factor (the Gamma factor) at a real or complex place $v$  can be constructed from the $K_v$-Hodge decomposition of $H^m(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C})$. What I don't understand is why this is a natural analogue of the characteristic polynomial of the action of Frobenius. Is there a conceptual explanation?

Comment: Do you know the work of Deninger "On the \Gamma factors attached to motives", Invent. Math. 104 (1991) 245-261?

Comment: Thank you, I will try to read through this paper. It seems to me that there must have been some intuition of the parallels between l-adic cohomology with Galois action and singular cohomology with Hodge structure before 1991. For example, something must have motivated Serre to define the gamma factors as he does in "Facteurs locaux...". Do you have any understanding of this? Maybe I will understand after I read Deninger.

Comment: The only motivation I see in the paper of Serre is that Gamma factors appear in the known examples (number fields, modular curves...) It would be great if someone could say if Serre had more conceptual motivations, I don't know.

Comment: About the date 1991: from what I understand, the story of the Deninger interpretation is somewhat involved: it is motivated by p-adic Hodge theory and not directly by the usual formulation of Hodge theory.

Comment: Another point: maybe Gamma factors at the Archimedean places are most easily undestood on the automorphic side of the story. I am certainly not an expert of these questions and I hope someone else will say more.

Comment: It seems clear to me that there should be a contribution from the archimedean places as much as there is at the non-archimedean ones. I'd be interested in the motivation for deducing its precise form from the Hodge structure. Alternatively, I guess, I'd be interested in understanding the factor at p in terms of p-adic Hodge theory. In short, I'd quite like have a uniform intuition covering all places. On the automorphic side, I thought that the archimedean components need not necessarily be of "Hodge type". Maybe I am wrong about that though.